# how to run beeline and hive query from a bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, hive, beeline

I am able to run below steps manually in order after logging in to unix bash shell.

```sh
echo "Connecting beeline" 

beeline
!connect jdbc:hive2://a301-1234-1234.stm.XXX.com:10000/default;;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/app/bds/cloudera_truststore.jks;sslTrustPassword=;principal=hive/_HOST@BDS.XXXX.COM

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "/dev/ref/HIVE_EXPORT/" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ESCAPED BY "\\" SELECT * FROM test_ref_st.Daily_report  limit 10;

hadoop fs -get('/dev/ref/HIVE_EXPORT/000000_0', '/user/rj/hiveExtract.csv')
echo "Query result extracted "
```

I need to run all above steps in sequence via a shell script test1.sh like

```sh
bash-4.2$ sh -x test1.sh
```

then it is only running till beeline and remaining commands are not being run.
Current output:

```sh
bash-4.2$ sh test1.sh

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:
Beeline version 1.1.0-cdh5.16.2 by Apache Hive
beeline>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash is processing your script line by line. It runs `beeline` and waits for your input.
You can use [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to write to stdin from your script:

```
beeline <<EOF
!connect jdbc:hive2://a301-1234-1234.stm.XXX.com:10000/default;;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/app/bds/cloudera_truststore.jks;sslTrustPassword=;principal=hive/_HOST@BDS.XXXX.COM
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "/dev/ref/HIVE_EXPORT/" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ESCAPED BY "\\" SELECT * FROM test_ref_st.Daily_report  limit 10;
EOF
```

Comment: Still not working getting error:
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:266 character '<EOF>' not supported here
line 1:154 character '\' not supported here
line 1:266 character '<EOF>' not supported here (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 3):

Using `!connect` will open up the beeline shell console. For using beeline CLI command you can do the following in SHELL:

```
#!/bin/bash

HIVE_CONN=jdbc:hive2://a301-1234-1234.stm.XXX.com:10000/default;;  ## limited for simplicity

echo "executing query using beeline"
beeline -u $HIVE_CONN -e "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY "/dev/ref/HIVE_EXPORT/" ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," ESCAPED BY "\\" SELECT * FROM test_ref_st.Daily_report  limit 10;"

... 
rest of your code
```

-e stand for the query you want to execute

More on [beeline CLI](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineExample) in here.